# Moment js diff with different timezone

Tags: datetime, timezone, momentjs, timezone-offset

I want to calculate the difference of time in hours between 2 different time zones using the moment.js library.

I tried using `diff` function provided by the library but it is not providing correct answers, I tried:

```
moment('2016-12-18 6:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
    .diff(moment('2016-12-18 6:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').utcOffset('+09:30'), 'hours')
```

I am in `UTC+5:30` and the `moment(string, string)` constructor returns the time in my current timezone. And I was expecting the answer to be `4` instead got `0`. Is there any other function that moment library provides to get difference amongst timezones ?

Comment: You probably need to use [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/). See [`utcOffset`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/) docs for further details.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you are just using fixed time zone offsets, your above code will work if you make one adjustment:

```
.utcOffset('+09:30', true)
```

The second parameter tells the function to retain the date and time value the moment already has when the offset is set.  The default (`false`) will *shift* the date and time from its current offset (your local time) to the offset provided.

If you are not working with fixed offsets, then you will indeed need to use the moment-timezone add-on.